Expansion of Complex Number
This has been asked before, but I am looking for a different approach strictly using binomial theorem and no trig/polar form.
This is the problem statement:

Let $z = 1 - i$. Compute $z^n$, where $n$ is a natural number.

My Approach:
For the problem, I should consider cases when $n = 4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, 4k+3$ where $k$ is an integer. But I having trouble. For now, I will only consider the case $n=4k$ to demonstrate where I'm having issues. From the binomial expansions of $(1-i)^n$, the real part of the expansion will be equal to the alternative sum/difference of even numbered indices of the binomial coefficient. This is equal to $$\frac{\left(1+i\right)^{n}+\left(1-i\right)^{n}}{2}$$
This doesn't really seem like a useful manipulation. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
Could anyone please help with this? Also, if possible, can you set up one of the other cases to give me a pointer?

Start by applying the binomial theorem, and use that
$$
i^n = \begin{cases}
i, & n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \
-1, & n \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \
-i, & n \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \
1, & n \equiv 0 \pmod 4
\end{cases}
\implies
(-i)^n = \begin{cases}
-i, & n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \
-1, & n \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \
i, & n \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \
1, & n \equiv 0 \pmod 4
\end{cases}
$$
so
$$
(1-i)^n =
\sum_{j \in {0,1,2,3}} \sum_{\substack{0 \le k \le n \ k \equiv j \pmod 4}} \binom n k (-i)^k
$$

The question is unclear. First of all, the story introduces a variable $k$, seems to consider only the case $n=4k$, but then things get complicated. The simple way to go would be to compute:$$(1-i)^2=1-2i-1=-2i\ ,\qquad(1-i)^4=(-2i)^2=-4\ .$$But ok, we go an other way. It seems that we want to compute the real part of $(1-i)^n$, not knowing it is a real number. (That "real part of the exponent" makes no sense, in the expression $(1-i)^n$ the base is $(1-i)$, the exponent is $n$.) Then we set something equal. Why (should equality hold)? Where is the question? In which direction to proceed?

"...I'm not sure how to proceed from here...." : The posted article seems vague to me.  It is not clear to me exactly what question that you are asking or math problem that you want solved.  I suggest that you overhaul your posted question, to shorten it, and succinctly express the specific question/problem that you want attacked.

I've rewritten the question.

If you insist on splitting $n$ into cases modulo $4$, you should first investigate what happens when we have $n=1,2,3,4$. Then, all cases from there immediately generalise. That is: \begin{align*} n = 1 &\implies (1-i)^1 = 1 - i; \\ n = 2 &\implies (1-i)^2 = -2i; \\ n = 3 &\implies (1-i)^3 = -2(i + 1); \\ n = 4 &\implies (1-i)^4 = -4. \end{align*} This is very promising, because it informs us that after every four iterations we ensure that the imaginary part of $z$ is annihilated. Immediately, we can conclude: \begin{align*} n = 4k &\implies (1-i)^{4k} =  (-4)^k; \\ n = 4k+1 &\implies (1-i)^{4k+1} = (1-i)^{4k}(1-i) = (-4)^k(1-i); \\ n = 4k+2 &\implies (1-i)^{4k+2} = (1-i)^{4k}(1-i)^2 = -2(-4)^ki; \\ n = 4k+3 &\implies (1-i)^{4k+3} = (1-i)^{4k}(1-i)^3 = -2(-4)^k(i+1). \end{align*}
If you want a completely general formula, refer to PrincessEev's comment.

Thanks for the answer! This is a much simpler solution. I was originally doing the same thing as PrincessEev, but I wasn't able to reduce the binomial coefficient summation to a closed form expression.
